# BT HC-06 not receiving data from 8051

Tags: bluetooth, arduino, microcontroller, android-bluetooth, 8051

I'm writing a code on my 8051 microcontroller on Silicon Labs IDE.

In my code i'm trying to communicate with the HC-06 module and send & receive data from an android app with a UART connection to my microcontroller board.

but i can't receive the data i'm sending from the microcontroller to the android app and i also cant receive the data i'm receiving from the android app on the microcontroller.

when I've checked the Rx & Tx of my UART the data was sent correctly. so the problem is in the HC-06 module.

**this is my UART interrupt code (in the Silicon Labs IDE):**

```
void UART0_BT_ISR(void) interrupt 4
{

    if(TI0==1)
    {
        TI0=0;
        while(TI0 == 0);
        TI0=0;
    }   
    if(RI0==1)
    {
        UART0_Buffer[BTi]=SBUF0;
        BTi++;
        RI0 = 0;
    }


}

void SendUARTData(char* FunkKey)
{

    i=0;
    while(1)
    {
        if(TI0==0)
        {
            SBUF0=FunkKey[i];
            i++;
            TI0=1;
        }
        if(i>16)
        {
            return;
            i=0;
        }
    }

}
```

**and this is my init_devide code:**

```
#include "compiler_defs.h"
#include "C8051F020_defs.h"

// Peripheral specific initialization functions,
// Called from the Init_Device() function
void Reset_Sources_Init()
{
    WDTCN     = 0xDE;
    WDTCN     = 0xAD;
}

void Timer_Init()
{
    CKCON     = 0x30;
    TCON      = 0x40;
    TMOD      = 0x20;
    TH1       = 0xB8;
    T2CON     = 0x34;
    RCAP2L    = 0xB8;
    RCAP2H    = 0xFF;
}

void UART_Init()
{
    SCON0     = 0x50;
    SCON1     = 0x40;
}

void Port_IO_Init()
{
    // P0.0  -  TX0 (UART0), Push-Pull,  Digital
    // P0.1  -  RX0 (UART0), Open-Drain, Digital
    // P0.2  -  TX1 (UART1), Push-Pull,  Digital
    // P0.3  -  RX1 (UART1), Open-Drain, Digital
    // P0.4  -  Unassigned,  Open-Drain, Digital
    // P0.5  -  Unassigned,  Open-Drain, Digital
    // P0.6  -  Unassigned,  Open-Drain, Digital
    // P0.7  -  Unassigned,  Open-Drain, Digital

    // P1.0  -  Unassigned,  Push-Pull,  Digital
    // P1.1  -  Unassigned,  Push-Pull,  Digital
    // P1.2  -  Unassigned,  Push-Pull,  Digital
    // P1.3  -  Unassigned,  Open-Drain, Digital
    // P1.4  -  Unassigned,  Open-Drain, Digital
    // P1.5  -  Unassigned,  Push-Pull,  Digital
    // P1.6  -  Unassigned,  Push-Pull,  Digital
    // P1.7  -  Unassigned,  Push-Pull,  Digital

    // P2.0  -  Unassigned,  Open-Drain, Digital
    // P2.1  -  Unassigned,  Open-Drain, Digital
    // P2.2  -  Unassigned,  Open-Drain, Digital
    // P2.3  -  Unassigned,  Open-Drain, Digital
    // P2.4  -  Unassigned,  Open-Drain, Digital
    // P2.5  -  Unassigned,  Open-Drain, Digital
    // P2.6  -  Unassigned,  Open-Drain, Digital
    // P2.7  -  Unassigned,  Open-Drain, Digital

    // P3.0  -  Unassigned,  Open-Drain, Digital
    // P3.1  -  Unassigned,  Open-Drain, Digital
    // P3.2  -  Unassigned,  Open-Drain, Digital
    // P3.3  -  Unassigned,  Open-Drain, Digital
    // P3.4  -  Unassigned,  Push-Pull,  Digital
    // P3.5  -  Unassigned,  Push-Pull,  Digital
    // P3.6  -  Unassigned,  Push-Pull,  Digital
    // P3.7  -  Unassigned,  Push-Pull,  Digital

    P0MDOUT   = 0x05;
    P1MDOUT   = 0xE7;
    P3MDOUT   = 0xF0;
    XBR0      = 0x04;
    XBR2      = 0x44;
}

void Oscillator_Init()
{
    int i = 0;
    OSCXCN    = 0x67;
    for (i = 0; i < 3000; i++);  // Wait 1ms for initialization
    while ((OSCXCN & 0x80) == 0);
    OSCICN    = 0x0C;
}

void Interrupts_Init()
{
    IE        = 0x90;
    IP        = 0x10;
}

// Initialization function for device,
// Call Init_Device() from your main program
void Init_Device(void)
{
    Reset_Sources_Init();
    Timer_Init();
    UART_Init();
    Port_IO_Init();
    Oscillator_Init();
    Interrupts_Init();
}
```

my baud rate is set to 9600.

the BT HC-06 is connected to UART0.

can you tell me please what i'm doing wrong and why does my BT HC-06 is not working?

thank you very much
Reshef

Answer (score 1):

Ensure the following basic conditions are met,

**Connections**

1. Check ground is common. Module and chip are both powered on.
2. Ensure 8051_TX->Module_Rx and Module_Tx->8051_Rx connections.
3. Check if both are using 3.3V for communication (use resistor level shifters).

**Code checking**

1. Try shorting your chips Rx to Tx and see if you are able to receive an echo.
2. If you have a USB to UART converter, try connecting the module directly (check 
   voltages) and check data transfer.